# How can I change the keyboard layout before I log in?

Tags: debian, x11, keyboard-layout, gdm

In order to switch to a new keyboard layout I have added an `setxkbmap` command to my Openbox's `autostart.sh`.

However, this only takes effect once I log in (when Openbox starts).

*While* logging in, in GDM (I suppose), the layout I chose when installing the system is still active - which is distracting in my efforts.

What do I have to do to have this default layout changed?

(OS: Debian 7.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [Debian Wiki article](http://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard).  There are several approaches on that page probably the easiest is to run this command as root:

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Comment: you mean `# dpkg ...` I think.

Comment: @jcora nope, the command `dpkg-reconfigure` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it, is already covered by the answer from sim, but in case you are unable do run `dpkg-reconfigure` for some reason (suppose you have a chroot or something), you have to edit `/etc/default/keyboard`. This is also what the `dpkg-reconfigure` command does in the end but in a safe way using an easy to use interface.

Here is an example `/etc/default/keyboard` for the German Neo2 keyboard layout:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT="neo"
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Also, this will affect your initramfs. This is especially important if you configured full disk encryption where you have to type your password. To also immidiately update the initramfs you can run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```